# Why are two open sets isomorphic (Hartshorne Corollary I 4.5)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be birational varieties and $\phi: X \rightarrow Y, \psi: Y \rightarrow X$ mutually inverse rational dominant maps. Let $\phi$ be represented by $(U,\phi_U)$ and $\psi$ by $(V,\psi_V)$. The proof of Hartshorne's Corollary I 4.5 says that the open sets $\phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U)) \subset U$ and $\psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V)) \subset V$ are isomorphic via $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively.

However, I have a very basic question concerning this. I wonder why $\phi_U$ sends $\phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U))$ into $\psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V))$ (i.e. why the image is contained in the second set).

$\phi_U \circ  \phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U))\subset \psi_V^{-1}(U),$ but $\psi_V^{-1}(U)$ seems to be bigger than $\psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V))$? I guess I must have missed some information here.

Comment: $\phi_U \circ  \phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U))$ is smaller than $\psi_V^{-1}(U)$. Note that $\phi$ is an isomorphism $A\to \phi(A)$ iff it is regular on $A$ and $\psi$ is regular on $\phi(A)$, this is what your sets define.

Comment: @reuns  how do I prove $\phi_U \circ  \phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U))\subset \psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V))$?

Comment: @reuns i don't think so, By $\psi\circ\phi$ is identity on $\phi^{-1}(V)$, we have $\psi\circ\phi$ is also identity on $\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)$, thus $\psi\circ\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))=\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)$, thus 
$\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)\subset\psi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))\subset \psi^{-1}\phi^{-1}(V)$, i.e. $\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))\subset\psi^{-1}\phi^{-1}(V)$

Answer (score 2):

By $\psi\circ\phi$ is identity on $\phi^{-1}(V)$, we have $\psi\circ\phi$ is also identity on $\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)$, thus $\psi\circ\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))=\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)$, thus 
$\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U)\subset\psi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))\subset \psi^{-1}\phi^{-1}(V)$, i.e. $\phi(\phi^{-1}\psi^{-1}(U))\subset\psi^{-1}\phi^{-1}(V)$